# How to forward both right and left value reference in a template

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm confused about forwarding universe reference in templates. My code is as follows:

```
  class A {
  public:
      void fn(std::unique_ptr<std::string> n) {
          (*n) += "1";
          cout << "n: " << *n << endl;
      }

      void fn2(std::string& n) {
          n += "2";
          cout << "n: " << n << endl;
      }
  };

  template <typename Func, typename Class, typename... Args>
  std::thread create_thread(Func&& func, Class* this_ptr, Args&&... args) {
      auto handler = [&] {
          (this_ptr->*func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); // error
      };
      return std::thread(handler);
  }

  int main() {
      auto str1 = std::make_unique<std::string>("a");
      auto str2 = "b";
      A a;
      auto t1 = create_thread(&A::fn, &a, std::move(str1));
      auto t2 = create_thread(&A::fn2, &a, std::ref(str2));
      t1.join();
      t2.join();

      return 0;
  }
```

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::basic_string<char>&’ to an rvalue of type ‘std::basic_string<char>’
```

I also tried `std::forward(args...)` instead since C++17 can get template type automatically. Didn't work either (not suitable for `std::forward`?).

So how to forward both right and left value reference in one template function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side-note: You don't need a lambda to create threads calling member functions on an object, `std::thread` can handle that directly, so your function could just look like `{ return std::thread(func, this_ptr, args...); }` – you'll notice that the function call itself will not look any different from creating the thread directly: `std::thread t1(&A::fn, &a, std::move(str1))`, so you might ask yourself if you need that function at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str2` is a character array not a `std::string`, the compiler is trying to create a temporary `std::string` from your character array but as `fn2` takes a non-const reference a temporary value can't be used.

If you change `str2` to a `std:: string` it will probably compile.